# DOB Validation in Angular 6 Template Driven Form

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a DOB field which needs to have a max value to {{currentdate}}, my apparoach is to get the Current date in the TS file and use string interpolation in the HMTL 'max' validator, but using this

```
  date: Date = new Date();
```

returns this
Thu Jun 28 2018 12:11:34 GMT+0530 (IST)

Is there any I can make this work by formatting the returned date in a way that will match the validator's expected input?

**EDIT**
Here is the html:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

<h1>{{date}}</h1>

    <form (ngSubmit)="onSignUp(f)" #f="ngForm" >

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input 
        ngModel
        required
        type="text" name="firstName" id="fname">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input 
        ngModel
        required
        type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input 
        ngModel
        required
        type="email" name="email" id="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input
        ngModel
        required
        pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"
        type="password" name="password" id="password">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="verifyPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input 
        ngModel
        type="verifyPassword" name="verifyPassword" id="verifyPassword">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
        <input 
        max="2017-04-01"
        type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="flatPurchaceDate">Flat Purchace Date</label>
        <input 
        max="2017-04-01"        
        type="date" name="flatPurchaceDate" id="flatPurchaceDate">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="proficePicture">Profile Picture (URL)</label>
        <input type="text" name="profilePicture" id="profilePicture" placeholder="URL">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="flatBlock">Flat Block</label>
        <select id="flatBlock" name="flatBlock">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
        </select> 
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="flatNumber">Flat Number</label>
        <input 
        min="1" max="10"
        type="number" name="flatNumber" id="flatNumber" placeholder="URL">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</label>
        <input 
        pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{11}"
        type="tel" name="mobileNumber" id="mobileNumber">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subscribeNews">Terms and Conditions</label>          
        <input
        required
        type="checkbox" #terms id="terms" name="terms">
      </div>

      <button [disabled]="!f.valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('terms') terms: ElementRef ;
  
  constructor() { }
  date: Date = new Date();  
  
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  valid = this.terms.nativeElement.checked;
  
  onSignUp(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.terms);
    console.log(this.terms.nativeElement.checked);
  }
}
```

Ignore the part about the checkbox, that's another validation

Comment: Are you using a datepicker? Are you using reactive form? Can you show your form?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 2):

[Here is your solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vqmsq)

In HTML

```
        <h1>{{date}}</h1>

        <form (ngSubmit)="onSignUp(f)" #f="ngForm">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input ngModel required type="text" name="firstName" id="fname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input ngModel required type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input ngModel required type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input ngModel required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="verifyPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <input ngModel type="verifyPassword" name="verifyPassword" id="verifyPassword">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label> {{maxDate}}
                <input [max]="maxDate" (change)="dateChange($event.target.value)" type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="flatPurchaceDate">Flat Purchace Date</label>
                <input max="2017-04-01" type="date" name="flatPurchaceDate" id="flatPurchaceDate">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="proficePicture">Profile Picture (URL)</label>
                <input type="text" name="profilePicture" id="profilePicture" placeholder="URL">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="flatBlock">Flat Block</label>
                <select id="flatBlock" name="flatBlock">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
        </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="flatNumber">Flat Number</label>
                <input min="1" max="10" type="number" name="flatNumber" id="flatNumber" placeholder="URL">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</label>
                <input pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{11}" type="tel" name="mobileNumber" id="mobileNumber">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subscribeNews">Terms and Conditions</label>
                <input required type="checkbox"  name="terms">
            </div>

            <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent {

  date = new Date();  
  maxDate = (new Date().getFullYear()).toString()+"-0"+(new Date().getMonth()+1).toString()+"-"+(new Date().getDate()).toString();

  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.maxDate)

  }

  onSignUp(form: NgForm) {

    console.log(form.value);

  }

  dateChange(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here i have added '0' in month statically . i think you can change it easily.